# Gridview Vertical Header Text for Chrome

Tags: gridview, text

I am using the  `-webkit-transform: rotate(270deg)` to rotate the header text in my gridview so it is vertical.  The problem is the width of the header above each cell is staying the same instead of getting smaller.  Is there a way to change the width of each header cell so no extra space is on either side of the text?